# Is there a way to get the perfect (proper format) values from web page using encoding in python?

Tags: python, excel, function, csv, encoding

Problem : Things on webpage like AMD Ryzen™ 9 5950X, when i am getting it into csv file it shows up as : AMD Ryzenâ„¢ 9 5950X, 90°C shows up as 90Â°C. i have to write a function to get the exact(proper) values from the web page. i tried to capture and store these in .txt file. It shows up as perfectly normal values. Is excel/csv creating this problem? How can i solve this issue?

**config.ini**

```
[configData]
baseurl = https://www.amd.com/en/processors/ryzen
sub_url = https://www.amd.com
all_keys = Model,Platform,Product Family,Product Line,# of CPU Cores,# of Threads, Max. Boost Clock, Base Clock, Total L2 Cache, Total L3 Cache,Default TDP, Processor Technology for CPU Cores, Unlocked for Overclocking, CPU Socket,Thermal Solution (PIB), Max. Operating Temperature (Tjmax), Launch Date, *OS Support
```

**Main.py file code**

```
import logging
from data_extraction import data_extraction
from data_processing import data_processing
from configparser import ConfigParser


class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser()
        self.config.read('config.ini')
        logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                            format='%(asctime)s:%(lineno)d:%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

        self.baseurl = self.config['configData']['baseurl']
        self.sub_url = self.config['configData']['sub_url']
        self.all_keys = self.config['configData']['all_keys']
        # print(all_keys)
        self.all_keys = [key.strip() for key in self.all_keys.split(',')]

    def __Processing__(self):
        de = data_extraction(self.baseurl)
        dp = data_processing()
        self.model_links = de.get_links_in_list(self.sub_url)
        logging.debug(self.model_links)
        each_link_data = de.data_extraction(self.baseurl, self.all_keys, self.model_links)
        logging.info('data extraction is called from main')
        all_link_data = dp.data_processing(each_link_data)

        # calling function write_to_csv
        dp.write_to_csv(all_link_data,self.all_keys)
        logging.info('data copied to csv')
        dp.rectify_csv(str(all_link_data))

Main().__Processing__()
```

**DataExtraction.py**

```
import logging
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class data_extraction:
    def __init__(self, baseurl):
        self.headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36',
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", "DNT": "1",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

        r = requests.get(baseurl, headers=self.headers)
        status = r.status_code
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        self.model_links = []

    # function to get the model links in one list from soup object(1st page extraction)
    def get_links_in_list(self, sub_url):
        for model_list in self.soup.find_all('td', headers='view-name-table-column'):
            # model_list = model_list.a.text - to get the model names
            model_list = model_list.a.get('href')
            # print(model_list)
            model_list = sub_url + model_list
            # print(model_list)
            one_link = model_list.split(" ")[0]
            self.model_links.append(one_link)
        return self.model_links

    # function to get data for each link from the website(2nd page extraction)
    def data_extraction(self, baseurl, all_keys, model_links):
        r = requests.get(baseurl, headers=self.headers)
        status = r.status_code
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        each_link_data = []
        try:
            for link in model_links:
                r = requests.get(link, headers=self.headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
                specification = {}
                for key in all_keys:
                    spec = soup.select_one(
                        f'.field__label:-soup-contains("{key}") + .field__item, .field__label:-soup-contains("{key}") + .field__items .field__item')

                    # print(spec)
                    if spec is None:
                        specification[key] = ''
                        if key == 'Model':
                            specification[key] = [i.text for i in soup.select_one('.page-title')]
                            specification[key] = specification[key][0:1:1]
                            # print(specification[key])

                    else:

                        if key == '*OS Support':
                            specification[key] = [i.text for i in spec.parent.select('.field__item')]
                        else:
                            specification[key] = spec.text
                    specification['link'] = link
                    each_link_data.append(specification)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error occurred')
            logging.info('data not extracted')

        return each_link_data
        # print(each_link_data)
```

**Data processing.py**

```
import pandas as pd


class data_processing:
    # function for data processing : converting the each link object into dataframe

    def data_processing(self, each_link_data):
        all_link_data = []
        for each_linkdata_obj in each_link_data:
            # make the nested dictionary to normal dict
            norm_dict = dict()
            for key in each_linkdata_obj:
                if isinstance(each_linkdata_obj[key], list):
                    norm_dict[key] = ','.join(each_linkdata_obj[key])
                else:
                    norm_dict[key] = each_linkdata_obj[key]

            all_link_data.append(norm_dict)
        return all_link_data

    # function to write dataframe data into csv
    def write_to_csv(self, all_link_data, all_keys):
        all_link_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_link_data)
        all_link_df2 = all_link_df.drop_duplicates()
        all_link_df3 = all_link_df2.reset_index()
        # print(all_link_df3)
        all_keys = all_keys + ['link']
        all_link_df4 = all_link_df3[all_keys]
        # print(all_link_df4)
        all_link_df4.to_csv('final_data.csv', index=False)
        # all_link_df4.to_csv('final_data.xlsx',index=False)

    # function to remove unwanted characters from the csv file.
    def rectify_csv(self, all_link_df4):
        all_link_data_str = str(all_link_df4)
        with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(all_link_data_str)
```

**readme.txt:**

```
 'link': 'https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-5950x', 
 'Platform': 'Boxed Processor', 
 'Product Family': 'AMD Ryzen™ Processors', 
 'Product Line': 'AMD Ryzen™ 9 Desktop Processors', 
 '# of CPU Cores': '16', 
 '# of Threads': '32', 
 'Max. Boost Clock': 'Up to 4.9GHz', 
 'Base Clock': '3.4GHz', 
 'Total L2 Cache': '8MB', 
 'Total L3 Cache': '64MB', 
 'Default TDP': '105W', 
 'Processor Technology for CPU Cores': 'TSMC 7nm FinFET', 
 'Unlocked for Overclocking': 'Yes', 
 'CPU Socket': 'AM4', 
 'Thermal Solution (PIB)': 'Not included', 
 'Max. Operating Temperature (Tjmax)': '90°C', 
 'Launch Date': '11/5/2020', 
 '*OS Support': 'Windows 10 - 64-Bit Edition,RHEL x86 64-Bit,Ubuntu x86 64-Bit,*Operating System (OS) support will vary by manufacturer.'},
```

**final_data.csv**

```
AMD Ryzenâ„¢ 9 5950X Desktop Processors
AMD Ryzenâ„¢ Processors
AMD Ryzenâ„¢ 9 Desktop Processors
90Â°C
```

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the direct connection between *readme.txt* and `write_to_csv` is.

Comment: Hi @Booboo readme.txt shows that the data from the web page is in proper format. write_to_csv is used to write the same data in the csv file where - AMD Ryzen™ 9 5950X, when i am getting it into csv file it shows up as : AMD Ryzenâ„¢ 9 5950X, 90°C shows up as 90Â°C.  same data when written into a text file it's in readable format..

Comment: Hi @Booboo do you want me to elaborate more?
write to csv writes the same data in final_data.csv

Comment: It's the comment in `rectify_csv` (function to remove unwanted characters from the csv file) that is confusing. What is this actually doing? So is the data actually the same?

Comment: A flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (Python): `'Ryzen™ 90°C'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'Ryzenâ„¢ 90Â°C'`… There is insufficient [mcve] in your question so it's unanswerable.

Comment: @Booboo sorry ! the comment means tht i want to write that function for that purpose but currently it is just reading the data and keeping it in readme.txt

Comment: @JosefZ i did not understand what you said in the comment. To make my question more undestandable i am giving the whole code in the question. Let me know then if you undestand it. My basic question is why 'Ryzen™ 90°C' becomes  Ryzenâ„¢90Â°C in csv and it remains 'Ryzen™ 90°C in text file.

Comment: @JosefZ is correct, your data was unintentionally decoded with the CP1252 character encoding somewhere in the chain of steps leading up to `all_link_df4.to_csv('final_data.csv',index=False)`. If you include the values of `all_link_data` and `all_keys` in your Post, we might be able to help.

Comment: @ZachYoung ok i am trying to add the whole  code.

Comment: Before you add the whole code, please prove to yourself that the inputs to those two functions match your expectations. And, I just asked for the values of `all_link_data` and `all_keys`.

Comment: @ZachYoung those 2 functions do match the expectaion of the requirement. the values of ```all_link_data``` and ```all_keys``` are explained in the whole code. because i don't know how to explain them seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft software is infamous for assuming the contents of a file are encoded in the native Windows character encoding.  If your file is written in something reasonable like UTF-8 it is likely to be misinterpreted.

The way to get Microsoft applications like Excel to recognize UTF-8 properly is to put a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the front of the file.  Python can add this automatically if you open the file with `encoding='utf_8_sig'`.